# CSS, Classic ASP, Checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, asp-classic

I am trying to get my stylesheet to implement changes to a checkbox. I know the CSS is good because when it was inline, it worked like a champ.

internal_users.asp is the one that needs to be formatted but it inherits (similar to a masterpage) from i_internal_headers.asp where the styles are implements.

code:

```
stylesheet:
.checkbox {
margin: 4px 0;
padding: 0;
width:50px;
border:none;
background:none;
}

i_internal_headers.asp
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css">

internal_users.asp
<!-- #include file="include/i_internal_headers.asp" -->
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" value="" />
```

I have also tried on the stylesheet input[type=checkbox] {}

I also tried creating a brand new stylesheet called TrialCheckboxStylesheet.css and placed all of the css in there. still didn't work. and yes i put a new link ref in i_internal_headers

EDITTED:  My current code looks like this:

```
.cbClear {
margin: 4px 0;
padding: 0;
width:50px;
border:none;
background:none;
```

}

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbClear" value="" />.
```

When using Developer Tools on IE, I found this

```
#rightcolumn input, #rightcolumn textarea, #rightcolumn select { 
padding: 5px; 
width: 299px; 
font: 100% arial; 
border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; 
background: #FFF; 
color: #47433F;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
```

}

which seems to be overriding the other CSS for the checkbox.  So, how would I get the checkbox one to have priority over the other?

Comment: Check out the generated HTML and see what other places a style is being injected that is masking the styling you're expecting.

Comment: How do I do that?  Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: Firebug would be one way to inspect the HTML you have in the end.

Comment: The program will mostly be run in IE (various versions, but most will be up-to-date).  What would a program to test with IE be?

Comment: F12 dev tools would be a place to start. Or View Source.

Comment: Thank you!  I did Dev Tools and found out that the stylesheet is being called correctly.  Unfortunately,  <br/>#rightcolumn input, #rightcolumn textarea, #rightcolumn select { 
 padding: 5px; 
 width: 299px; 
 font: 100% arial; 
 border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; 
 background: #FFF; 
 color: #47433F;
 border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
 -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;  
}  <br/>
is somehow overriding the CSS for the checkbox.  How do I make my CSS for the checkbox not be overridden, or have the priority?

Comment: One option would be to make your selector for the style for the checkbox on the input more specific, use !important on the style components you need to take precedence, or both.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni
.cbClear {
    margin: 4px 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width:50px !important;
    border:none !important;
    background:none !important;
}


!important didn't work.
how do I code your other option?

Comment: .cbClear, #rightcolumn input.cbClear { .... } - see http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ for a tutorial on how the precedence calculation works.

Comment: Very good read, but being that .cbClear was the last entry in the stylesheet (as in the last one on the page), it should be the priority.  I did change it to this: .cbClear, #rightcolumn input.cbClear  and it still didn't work.

Comment: GOT IT!!!!  Thank you very much!  What I had to do was this:    "#rightcolumn input.cbClear"    Not this:   ".cbClear, #rightcolumn input.cbClear"    Thank you SO much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I had to do

```
#rightcolumn input.cbClear {
margin:4px 0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
width:50px !important;
border:none !important;
background:none !important;
```

}

inside the stylesheet.css

This made it the priority to override the prior CSS

Thank you Tetsujin no Oni for the help and quick answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are these two in the same CSS file? `#rightcolumn input, #rightcolumn textarea, #rightcolumn select` and `#rightcolumn input.cbClear`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the relative path of the css. As far I can assume your file structure is something like the following

```
root
|
|-include
  |-i_internal_headers.asp
|-css
  |-stylesheet.css
|-internal_users.asp
```

so when you are calling `internal_users.asp` file from browser it looks for the `stylesheet.css` file in a css folder which is located in the parent folder of the root folder. this problem occurs because you have given relative path for the stylesheet in `i_internal_headers.asp`

to solve this problem change the relative path to absolute path. like this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css"><!-- remove the two dots in from of /css -->
```

this tells the server that the stylesheet is located under `root/css` folder.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">

Comment: open `internal_users.asp` in chrome or firefox, right click on empty space and click `view page source`. in the source click the link for `/css/stylesheet.css`. it should open up the stylesheet.css in new page. if the stylesheet doesn't open up then the problem lies with resolving the location of the stylesheet.

Comment: Great advice!  It did open up with those changes you asked me to make.  Unfortunately, it didn't cause any CSS change.